# PDO SQL Bug? Error 1140: Mixing of GROUP columns with no GROUP columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following query:

```
select
    count(*) as aggregate
from
    `images`
where
    `images`.`imageable_id` = ?
    and `images`.`imageable_id` is not null
    and `images`.`imageable_type` = ?
    and `generated` = ?
order by
    `order` asc
```

When I run this in the MySQL REPL it works perfectly. However when I run it in PHP with PDO, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

I'm running PHP version `7.0.23-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`

Does anyone have a hint on how to diagnose and cure this issue?

Comment: I'm accessing the REPL with `mysql -u <user>` and PDO is accessing localhost on port 3306 -- so I believe it's the same instance. The MySQL server version is 5.5.57

Comment: I ran `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT VERSION();"); $stmt->execute(); var_dump($stmt->fetch());` and it returned an array with two elements: `["VERSION()" => "5.5.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1", 0 => "5.5.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1"]`

Comment: @chris85 It's not that strange if you want the total count of all matching rows. What's weird is the `order by` clause on a query guaranteed to return one row, but that's a quirk of how Laravel is generating the query so I can't do much about it. Regardless, the issue doesn't occur in the REPL, so I don't think that's the cause.

Comment: Oh, yes, I inverted the usage, that actually isnt the 5.6 vs. 5.7 issue either. I still am not sure why the error would different between PDO and mysql. PDO should just be returning what mysql threw.

Comment: Here's a fun bit of trivia to add to my dilemma... I upgraded to MySQL 5.7 just to see if it would help. Now PHP started throwing an error much earlier in my code, when performing a simple `insert` statement. The error is that the maximum memory was exceeded. Here's where it gets weirder: My `php.ini` file has `memory_limit = -1`, but it's limiting me to 128MB. Why would upgrading MySQL cause an insert statement to suddenly need more memory? And why is my `php.ini` being ignored?

Comment: I passed this problem around to some developers I knew and one figured it out. PDO is being initialized with `"strict" => true`, whereas the MySQL REPL is running in non-strict mode. Apparently in strict mode any columns that appear in an `order by` statement have to appear in a `group by` statement.

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen PDO set that. That is the setting that 5.7 has on by default.

Comment: Really unsure why this got a downvote with no explanatory comment. I had a legitimate issue with a specific and direct solution, and it's an issue that I'm **sure** someone else will have in the future.

Comment: Not sure of that, balanced out now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, when two connections to the same server are behaving differently, [check the mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

It turns out PDO was running in `strict` mode and the MySQL REPL was not.